# Where is Steve?

Tags: cipher, visual

Steve is a modern painter. He and his brother live in England. Today his brother found him missing. He searched everywhere, but couldn't find Steve. But in Steve's room, he found the below painting.
[image]

Now its time to become Sherlock Holmes. Can you find where Steve is ?

[image]

HINT

> WC (not water closet!)

Comment: Color and England force me think about cricket, but not able to find out any way...

Comment: Yes it's related to Cricket and today.....

Comment: ***The mind is everything!***

Comment: @Ak19 What you think,... *Shh...* **I know it, working on it...** ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steve is at the

> Oval

The cipher

> encoded in a font named "wc rhesus b bta". This piece of information can be found at the OP's bio ;)

Text:

> I am going to the Oval, to watch today’s first ICC WC match.

Comment: It's correct 

Comment: Pbatengf ba 7X!

Comment: it's 7k lol, thanks anyway :) @Ak19

Comment: Fbeel _ 7X BX ;)!!!

Comment: lets prevent excessive comments here and chat here instead: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93544/oks-home