# Steve asks his brother to book tickets

Tags: knowledge, visual

Congrats! $\Omega$ Krypton for finding the answer of :[Where is Steve?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84520/where-is-steve)

---

Yesterday England won the first match of the ICC World Cup 2019 by 104 runs. Steve is extremely happy now. He asks his brother to book tickets for another Cricket match. Instead of mentioning the stadium's name, he sends the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> ## Help Steve's brother to find the stadium!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: the stadium is

> **Trent Bridge**, Nottingham
>
>  Because:
>  The third image shows the Roman numerals  DCLVIII - VIII
>  These are the Arabic numerals 658 - 8
>  England scored 658 for 8 in their first innings here in 1938 against Australia.

Edit:

> Do the first two pictures refer to Harry Potter and the afternoon tea in Nottingham, at the Colwick Hall Hotel?

Edit 2:

> 1. Daniel Radcliffe: the village Radcliffe on Trent, near Nottingham.
>  2. Harry Potter and the afternoon tea in Nottingham, at the Colwick Hall Hotel.
>  3. The cricket score 658 for 8, in the 1938 first test at Trent Bridge.

Comment: A perfect catch!

Comment: It was a googly.

Comment: hahaha, anyways, you've found it !