# Steve misses _________?

Tags: knowledge, visual

Congrats! Weather Vane for finding the answer of :[Steve asks his brother to book tickets](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84569/steve-asks-his-brother-to-book-tickets/84572?noredirect=1#comment245470_84572)

---

$\bullet$Yesterday West Indies won by 7 wickets against Pakistan.

Even though Steve belongs to England, he loves Cricket players of other countries too. In this World Cup, Steve misses one of his favorite players.

EDIT: But the team the player belongs to is still there in this world cup.

> From the pictures below, can you find whom does he miss?

[image]

[image]

HINT

> rad$(2\pi)$

Comment: Rot13(Qbrf vg unir gb qb jvgu gnh (2cv?))

Comment: Vf lbhe zbqry fubjvat 57.3 qrterrf, n enqvna?

Comment: N shyy pvepyr? 360 qrterrf?

Comment: Gur ragver pvepyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> AB De Villiers

Because

> It is 2pi rad, a circle, which is the 360 degrees that he is famous for, and the second one, you rot13 the letters, which turn out to be abde, which ~ AB de Villiers.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the correct answer. The second one has something more related to that player

Comment: So the first name is wrong too?

Comment: Yes, the team is still there in this world cup. But New Guinea isn't there.

Comment: That leaves... 10 teams

Comment: Sorry, trying from memory..

Comment: Brings back great cricket memories