# Steve makes a riddle!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

<sup>Congrats! Duck for finding the answer of : [Steve misses _________?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84604/steve-misses)</sup>

$\bullet$ Yesterday New Zealand won against  Sri Lanka by 10 wickets!

$\bullet$ Australia won against Afghanistan by 7 wickets.

Steve poses the following riddle (Cricket Player)

> I wear a jersey of wonders,
> And many a times I make wonders.
> I often take risk(s),
> But I always remain brisk.
> I am from a team that roars,
> At the end, you can't stop me getting scores!
> At the end I become fierce as a storm,
> But other than this I remain calm!

## Who am I?

[image]

> A hint may be below this line!

Comment: Fhfcrpgvat Onatynqrfu be Fev Ynaxn grnzf.

Comment: Fbeel,  V qba'g xabj ;)

Comment: Ohg Fev Ynaxn pevpxrg grnz nyfb svgf "wrefrl bs jbaqref" nf vg vf znqr sebz erplpyrq jnfgr.

Comment: Ohg gur erznvavat yvarf qba'g zngpu

Comment: Uzz.. jvyy xrrc gelvat.

Comment: Best of luck! 

Comment: Is he still alive?

Comment: Yvbaf ebne ~ Ratynaq Yvbaf

Comment: Lrf ur'f fgvyy nyvir!

Comment: @duck $@$Ak19 - You might consider using this format for [rot13 comments](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6577):  rot13(Uv zbz!). One of our regulars [wrote a userscript](//stackapps.com/q/7927) to decode rot13 text on hover, and using that format for such text is a welcome convenience for those of us with that userscript.

Comment: @Rubio Sorry and Thanks for your advice. I will follow in my future comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think answer is

> M.S Dhoni

What I assume for each line.

I wear a jersey of wonders,

> His jersey number is 7. Also 7 wonders in world :)

And many a times I make wonders.

> Yes, he did many time wonders. Ex. Difficult decision on field, Quick stumping, Back throw on stump.

I often take risk(s),

> We all knew he always taking risk while doing batting or as captain in CSK or India.

But I always remain brisk.

> He is very fast in stumping.

I am from a team that roars,

> CSK.

At the end, you can't stop me getting scores!

> When he batting in death over, no one can stop him to getting score.

At the end I become fierce as a storm,

> Like as above comment.

But other than this I remain calm!

> Captain Cool.

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! (The first one I thought and made is for 7 - 7 wonders) but anyways +1

Comment: @Ak19 I have checked your profile many times in last week and I knew you are big fans of CSK and Dhoni. :)