# Steve's crossword

Tags: crosswords

<sup>Congrats! **Niranj Patel** for finding the answer of  [Steve makes a riddle!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84626/steve-makes-a-riddle)</sup>

$\bullet$ Yesterday Bangladesh won against South Africa by 21 runs.

Here's a crossword made by Steve. Fill it with the names of Cricket players.

[image]

ACROSS

> 2  Mr. Fantastic
> 7  Hitman
> 12 Kung fu
> 13 Watto
> 14 The Champion and Music
> 15 Superman

DOWN

> 1  Steady the Ship
> 3  The Slinga
> 4  Express + Leg-spin
> 5  Boom Boom !!!
> 6  Enigma
> 8  The Boss
> 9  The Big Show
> 10 The Untold Story
> 11 New Balance and me...
> 16 Moggie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACROSS

2 Mr. Fantastic

> Brendon McCullum

7 Hitman

> Rohit Sharma

12 Kung fu

> Hardik Pandya

13 Watto

> Shane Waston

14 The Champion and Music

> DJ Bravo

15 Superman

> AB DE Villiers

DOWN

1 Steady the Ship

> Kane Williamson

3 The Slinga

> Lasith Malinga

4 Express + Leg-spin

> Imran Tahir

5 Boom Boom  !!!

> Shahid Afridi

6 Enigma

> Faf Du Plessis : Using IXU bat

8 The Boss

> Chris Gayle

9 The Big Show

> Glenn Maxwell

10 The Untold Story

> M S Dhoni

11 New Balance and me...

> Steve smith : Using NB bat

16 Moggie

> Eoin Morgan

Comment: EXCELLENT! Got all correct!

Comment: @Ak19 Yes, may be typo mistake :)

Comment: Can you please explain some of these answers? I am a bit lost here. Why is Enigma=FDP, for instance?

Comment: @Sid His bat brand IXU