# Find this Cricket terminology

Tags: riddle

<sup>Congrats **Niranj Patel** for finding the answer of [Steve's crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84642/steves-crossword)</sup>

---

**Find this Cricket Terminology.**

> *A part of me is famous for a drink,*
>
> *I'll make the batsman out in a blink !*
>
> *Sometimes I may be equivalent to a wrong'un,*
>
> *But definitely make the batsman stun.*
>
> *Again, I'm not right*
>
> *This is my riddle for tonight.*
>
> *Finally, a  part of me is a guy*
>
> *That's all, give it a try !*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you the

> [Slow left arm wrist-spin bowling technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-arm_unorthodox_spin) formerly known as **[Chinaman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAXpXGFS2AI)**?

*A part of me is famous for a drink,*

> Since we are talking about cricket, the drink is probably tea, which is a drink famously from **China**, and also served in china teacups. ("Punch **bowl**" also crossed my mind, but I liked the other one better)

*I'll make the batsman out in a blink!*

> The chinaman spin is surprisingly strong, and in a surprising direction, so it's easy to miss altogether, resulting in the batsman instantly losing his wicket

*Sometimes I may be equivalent to a wrong'un,*

> In cricket terminology, a "wrong'un" is a delivery that spins "the other way" than usual. A chinaman bowler is always left-handed, but the spin is like that of a right-handed spin bowler, so that probably counts.

*But definitely make the batsman stun.*

> (Didn't really have anything for this.)

*Again, I'm not right*

> Chinaman bowling is done with the left hand

*This is my riddle for tonight.*

> Tonight is special, because tonight we don't talk (with or without Alan Partridge) about what happened at the "chinaman square" [exactly 30 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Tiananmen_Square_protests).

*Finally, a part of me is a guy*

> China**man**

*That's all, give it a try !*

The closest I've ever been to actually seeing anyone play cricket is that I spotted some cricket grounds in Regent's Park on my trip to London once, so this is absolutely my very bestest try :-)

Comment: Hmm, I definitely think this is it. Then again, I know nothing about cricket whatsoever. Definitely better than my two attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Longshot here, but are you

> The Riddler, from Bat-Man?

A part of me is famous for a drink,

> Perhaps referring to the Riddler's Revenge, a greenapple vodka cocktail

I'll make the batsman out in a blink !

> He coaxes Bat-Man into solving riddles.

Sometimes I may be equivalent to a wrong'un

> He's a criminal.

But definitely make the batsman stun.

> Bat-Man has to take time to solve the Riddler's riddles.

Again, I'm not right

> He's a bad guy, reiterated.

This is my riddle for tonight.

Finally, a part of me is a guy

> I'm pretty sure this is referring to part of the word itself. I got nothing for this. Unless you are referring to the Riddler being Edward Nigma.

Comment: Sorry, it's not. I've mentioned it's related to Cricket.

Comment: I'll add it in the header too.

Answer (score 1):

Okay 2nd Try

Are you a

> Striker?

A part of me is famous for a drink,

> Strike, possibly referring to Gold Strike, a cinnamon liqueur containing gold snippets.

I'll make the batsman out in a blink !

> The striker is the batsman, so of course he'll make him out, it's him.

Sometimes I may be equivalent to a wrong'un

> Strike, referring to a bad thing, like "Three strikes and you're out."

But definitely make the batsman stun.

> This could be a play on words. The batsman can be the striker. When you strike something, it stuns you.

Again, I'm not right

> Again, a strike against your record is bad.

Finally, a part of me is a guy

> Riker, a name popularized by Star Trek.