# Cricket or Cipher?

Tags: knowledge, cipher

<sup>Congrats **Bass** for finding the answer of [Find this Cricket terminology](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84679/find-this-cricket-terminology)</sup>

---

**Find the names of three Cricket stadiums from the below codes:**

1.

> ## dy30q7i

2.

> ## 23jgo36

3.

> ## 5y39fqo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decipher,

> [image]
>  see the letter below the characters. For example D will be C, Y will be H, 3 will be E, and so on.

So we will have

> 1. CHEPAUK
>  2. WEMBLEY
>  3. THEOVAL

Comment: Excellent @athin! +1