# Find Stack Exchange(s)!

Tags: knowledge

<sup>Congrats **athin** for finding the answer of [Cricket or Cipher?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84726/cricket-or-cipher)</sup>

---

Find the corresponding Stack Exchange sites from the tags given below.

For each site ***three*** tags are given.

> 1. konica, 11.10, 17.04
> 2. turbine, wind, taxiing
> 3. encryption, ssh, scrypt
> 4. ethics, lunch, bonus
> 5. no-computers, poetry, magic
> 6. topology, many-body, free fall
> 7. lie-groups, puzzle, roots
> 8. api-v2.2, authentication, c#
> 9. outreach, ethics, soy
> 10. adb, security, xiaomi
> 11. down-votes, not-an-answer, gravatar
> 12. syntaxe, noms, argot
> 13. milk, roast, cup
> 14. electricity, ab-initio, wax
> 15. ev3-g, motor, color
> 16. koma-script, texlive, siunitx
> 17. uri, apache, aegir
> 18. rice, ice-cream, curry
> 19. plot, copyright, comics
> 20. law, design, prior-art

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1: konica, 11.10, 17.04

> [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/konica+or+11.10+or+17.04)

2: turbine, wind, taxiing

> [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbine+or+wind+or+taxiing)

3: encryption, ssh, scrypt

> [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption+or+ssh+or+scrypt)

4: ethics, lunch, bonus

> [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics+or+lunch+or+bonus)

5: no-computers, poetry, magic

> [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-computers+or+poetry+or+magic)

6: topology, many-body, free fall

> [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology+or+many-body+or+free-fall)

7: lie-groups, puzzles, roots

> [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-groups+or+puzzles+or+roots)

8: api-v2.2, authentication, c#

> [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/api-v2.2+or+authentication+or+c#)

9: outreach, ethics, soy

> [Vegetarianism & Veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outreach+or+ethics+or+soy)

10: adb, security, xiaomi

> [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb+or+security+or+xiaomi)

11: down-votes, not-an-answer, gravatar

> [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/down-votes+or+not-an-answer+or+gravatar)

12: syntaxe, noms, argot

> [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntaxe+or+noms+or+argot)

13: milk, roast, cup

> [Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milk+or+roast+or+cup)

14: electricity, ab-initio, wax

> [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity+or+ab-initio+or+wax)

15: ev3-g, motor, color

> [Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev3-g+or+motor+or+color)

16: koma-script, texlive, siunitx

> [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koma-script+or+texlive+or+siunitx)

17: uri, apache, aegir

> [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uri+or+apache+or+aegir)

18: rice, ice-cream, curry

> [Cooking / Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rice+or+ice-cream+or+curry)

19: plot, copyright, comics

> [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot+or+copyright+or+comics)

20: law, design, prior-art

> [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law+or+design+or+prior-art)

Comment: Please check #15

Comment: Sorry please also check #19

Comment: @Ak19 - how about now?

Comment: YES ALL CORRECT.

Answer (score 5):

1. konica, 11.10, 17.04

   > Ask Ubuntu
2. turbine, wind, taxiing

   > Aviation (@Mith)
3. encryption, ssh, scrypt

   > Security (@Mith)
4. ethics, lunch, bonus

   > Workplace
5. no-computers, poetry, magic

   > Puzzling
6. topology, many-body, free fall

   > Physics
7. lie-groups, puzzles, roots

   > Mathematics
8. api-v2.2, authentication, c#

   > Stack Apps
9. outreach, ethics, soy

   > Vegetarianism & Veganism (@Mith)
10. adb, security, xiaomi

    > Android (@Mith)
11. down-votes, not-an-answer, gravatar

    > Meta (@Mith)
12. syntaxe, noms, argot

    > French Language (@Mith)
13. milk, roast, cup

    > Coffee (@Mith)
14. electricity, ab-initio, wax

    > Chemistry
15. ev3-g, motor, color

    > Bricks
16. koma-script, texlive, siunitx

    > TeX - LaTeX
17. uri, apache, aegir

    > Drupal
18. rice, ice-cream, curry

    > Cooking (@Mith)
19. plot, copyright, comics

    > Writing
20. law, design, prior-art

    > Ask Patents

Comment: Actually, there is a "puzzle" tag for #7, but no "puzzles" tag.

Comment: Yeah, that's what was holding me back on that -- wasn't sure if it was a typo or not.

Comment: Please check #15.

Comment: @Ak19 updated -- how does this look?

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, @Ak19.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry please also check #19

Comment: Perfect !!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, hey. :) I promise I wasn't looking at your answer, I was doing all my checking myself ;)

Comment: Haha no worries, great answer @Mithrandir! Well-deserved checkmark!